# The URL is not like what I want

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I press on submit button on form in CodeIgniter,
if I am at `XController/loadX`
and my action is `YController/loadY`,
the URL becomes like `Xcontroller/loadX/Ycontriller/loadY`,
and I want it to be just `YController/loadY`.

```
  <form name="SpecAccept"method="post"action="SpecialistController/loadDoctor">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12" id="myDiv" align="right">
        <span><label>الولاية</label></span>
        <select style="font-size:12px"  class="form-control" id="state_name" onchange="change(this)">
            <option>--- اختر الولاية ---</option>
            <?php
                foreach($states as $Object){
                echo '<option value="'.$Object->StateID.'">'.$Object->StateName.'</option>';
                }
            ?>

        </select>   
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6" id="myDiv" align="right">
        <span><label>المهنة</label></span>
        <select style="font-size:12px" class="form-control" id="career_name" >
            <option>--- اختر المهنة ---</option>
            <?php
                foreach($careers as $Object){
                echo '<option value="'.$Object->CareerID.'">'.$Object->CareerName.'</option>';
                }
            ?>

        </select>   
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6" id="myDiv" align="right">
        <span><label>المستشفى</label></span>
        <select style="font-size:12px"  class="form-control" id="hospitals" name="Hospitals" >
            <option value="0" isSelected>اختر الولاية اولاً</option>
        </select>
    </div>                                          
   <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <button type="sumbit">عرض</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

what is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: add a `/` infront of the URL in `action=""`

Comment: if I did that it will not send values to controller @modsfabio

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Then your question is more specific and we need your code..

Comment: I did edited the questuin

Comment: helloooooooooooooo ?

Comment: Lower case better for using in base url `<?php echo base_url('specialistcontroller/loaddoctor'); ?>` then controller name would be Specialistcontroller.php where only the first letter is upper case for class and filename https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 1):

try to use javascript

```
<button type="button" onclick="Function_name();" >عرض</button>
```

then in a javascript you can do that

```
<script>
function Function_name(){
alert ('I AM HERE');
document.SpecAccept.submit();
}
   </script>
```

that alert is to see if the button works and enter in the function.

if that not work try to change the type of form like this

```
<?php
    $attributes = array(
                    'id' => 'SpecAccept',
                    'name' => 'SpecAccept',
                    'autocomplete' => 'off',
                    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                );
               echo form_open_multipart('SpecialistController/loadDoctor'); // this is the open <form>
?>
```

then for closed it replaces `</form>` tag for

```
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define base URL in config.php file like this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectfoldername/';
```

Now in form action URL

```
<form name="SpecAccept"method="post"action="<?php echo base_url('SpecialistController/loadDoctor'); ?> ">
```

Comment: Lower case better for using in base url `<?php echo base_url('specialistcontroller/loaddoctor'); ?>` then controller name would be Specialistcontroller.php where only the first letter is upper case for class and filename https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming